# Ordering Seaborn heatmap with non-index variable

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I am currently in the process of moving from `R` and `ggplot2` to `seaborn` for a lot of work because R was struggling with the size of data I was using. I am currently working on a heatmap that is fairly simplistic and I have been able to render the general heatmap without too many issues, but I am not sure how to adjust the ordering of my categoricals for the heatmap.

In this case my data has this header:

`Sample    Position    Depth    Order`

Sample is the "y-axis" categorical and Position is the "x-axis" categorical. Depth is the value of the cell. Order is a meta-value calculated elsewhere, but I want to use Order as my ordering value for the y-axis, while retaining Sample as the label. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and where it's not working for you. Ideally, a [minimal repeatable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a rectangular format, or matrix for sns.heatmap, so though you have a `Order` column for ordering `Sample`, it's not clear whether there is a unique value for each `'Order'` category.

Below I use a simple example, and basically you change the 'Sample' to a category, according to the mean value of 'Order'. It is like changing the factor levels in R. Also, you need to make sure there is no NaN otherwise the heatmap might complain:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample':np.repeat(['A','B','C'],4),
                   'Position':[1,2,3,4]*3,
                   'Depth':np.random.normal(0,1,12),
                   'Order':np.repeat([2,1,3],4)})

y_order = df.groupby('Sample')['Order'].agg('mean').sort_values().index
df['Sample'] = pd.Categorical(df['Sample'],ordered=True,categories=y_order)
sns.heatmap(df.pivot(index='Sample',columns='Position', values='Depth'))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for, though I still need to test it, but essentially I was looking for the seaborn/pandas equivalent of factor levels.